# Connection Pool Leak Causes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have been experiencing (I think) issues with my connection pooling.
Specifically, my logs show the message:

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.DefaultPooledObject$AbandonedObjectCreatedException: Pooled object created [time] by the following code has not been returned to the pool

I have inspected the methods listed in the stack trace that the logs show but couldn't find a culprit (I always close the `ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement` and `Connection` at the end of each method).

I have a method that executes two queries, perhaps I am not executing it properly.

It's layout is as follows:

```
ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
PreparedStatement rowsPs = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSet rowsRs = null;

String query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...";
String totalRowsQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS RowCount";

try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    [set ps params]
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    [process rs]

    rowsPs = connection.prepareStatement(totalRowsQuery);
    rowsRs = rowsPs.executeQuery();
    [process rowsRs]
} catch (SQLException e) {
    [handle e]
} finally {
    DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
    [close rowsRs]
    [close ps]
    [close rowsPs]
    [close connection]
}
```

Where an example of a DBUtils method is:

```
public static void closeResultSet(ResultSet rs)
{
    try
    {
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does the general layout of this method seem ok? Should I be handling the connection differently? Or is it some other method that's causing the errors to be logged?

Thank you.

**Additional Info**

I also get a `SQLException`:

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@[some number] is closed

at the line: `rowsPs = connection.prepareStatement(totalRowsQuery);`

Meaning that somewhere prior, the connection is closed.
I don't explicitly close the connection anywhere.
Is it possible that some other data accessing method that is called is somehow closing the connection in this method? (`pool.getConnection()` calls `dataSource.getConnection()`)

**Update**:
I have tried using try-with-resources as suggested but the issue persists.

The ConnectionPool class that is referenced in the first code snippet above:

```
public class ConnectionPool 
{

    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    public synchronized static ConnectionPool getInstance()
    {

        if ( pool == null ) {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
            return pool;
    }

    private ConnectionPool()
    {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) 
                    ic.lookup([jdbc/dbName]);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void freeConnection(Connection c)
    { 
        try {
            c.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**More source**:
My Pool Resource Element:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
            logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            testWhileIdle="true" testOnBorrow="true" 
            validationQuery="SELECT 1 AS dbcp_connection_test"/>
```

**Update:**
I have turned on the slow query log but, despite the `Exception`s being thrown again, the slow query log does not log anything (no query takes longer than 10 seconds).

So it appears that it in not that the query is taking longer than 60 seconds.

Still uncertain as to what is causing this.

Comment: What if a line in `finally` fails? No downstream lines will be executed. I'd just close the connection because all sane JDBC implementations will cascade-close all its associated resources.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it doesn't really get to the root of the problem. Do you see any reason why lines in that `finally` clause would fail?

Comment: Yes, each line may throw an exception. That sort of reason.

Comment: I would see those exceptions in my log, no? I print them. All resources are closed via a util class that surrounds the statement in a `try` clause and prints the stacktrace if an exception is thrown.

Comment: A connection is obtained with `pool.getConnection()` and released with `connection.close()`, that's the pool's invariant. So you'd better find a reason why the line `connection.close()` is either not reached, or fails with an exception. Or, as an even more exotic explanation, the variable `connection` is reassigned and the original connection abandoned.

Comment: hmm, is it safe to get several connections from the `DataSource`? For example, within a method like the one above, I call several other database accessing methods which have the same general layout (each gets a connection and then closes it). Is there a limit to how many connections I can get while others are still open?

Comment: Use try-with-resources and most of your problems will probably go away.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would place my `rs` and `ps` in the try with resources but I don't see how that would change anything. At the moment, these resources are closed in the finally block and wrapped in try-catch statements.

Comment: If the close of any of those fail, then the connection close never happens; using try-with-resources protects you against that without needing a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks. Am I missing something about how exceptions work? the calls in my code snippet above such as "close rs" are done in util methods that surround `rs.close()` in a try and catch block (I updated the question with a sample of this code). Wouldn't that mean that, even if `rs.close()` fails, the code just "picks up" from the next line in the finally block (ie: "close rowRs") rather than escaping from the entire method?

Comment: It could be a very slow query. That log basically is saying a connection has been used by someone for too long. The pool cannot know whether it's a leak or the client simply runs slow.

Comment: Why does the client's speed affect the query? The query happens on my server.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto It's a singleton class for getting connections from the Connection Pool. It's very straightforward. I can post the code, let me know if you need it.

Comment: how long are your queries?

Comment: I suspect your connection to be already abandoned before you try to launch the second query assuming that the first query last more than `60` sec, try to increase `removeAbandonedTimeout` to `300`

Comment: The query that has been showing up in the stack traces of this issue is indeed my longest (in terms of lines). Approximately 60 lines long (I'm guessing it's bad practice to have such long queries). However, when I run it, it doesn't take nearly 60 seconds to execute (more like 1-2).

Comment: You might be on to something with the length of the query (because like I said, the query is my longest); but can a query that ordinarily takes `1-2` seconds take more than `60` seconds?

Comment: Both error messages indicate that you're referencing same connection in multiple places. You could prove it with database logs. Have you tried enforcing connection exclusivity? (by looking at your code, you did not) The contract is as follows, each borrowed connection needs to be returned into the pool, you are getting errors because two statements borrowed same ref and you can only close (return) it once. Is it possible that you have a race condition here `pool.getConnection()` ? Try and sync it.

Comment: @Palcente This sounds logical, let me check this issue and I'll update you. I haven't checked DB logs, but access logs might confirm what you are describing. Thanks.

Comment: @Palcente doesn't the connection pool ensure synchronization?

Comment: Is `Connection connection` really a method local variable? Can you make it `final`, just in case?

Answer (score 3):

As general rules of thumb when working with pooled JDBC connections:

1. Do not keep more than one ResultSet open at a time on each connection. Close the first ResultSet and its associated Statement before opening the second.
2. Always close the resources in exactly the reverse order that you created them: create(s1)->execute(r1)->close(r1)->close(s1)->create(s2)->execute(r2)->close(r2)->close(s2)
3. Ensure that a long running query processing is not exceeding the maximum connection lifetime allowed by the pool.
4. Even if you are not exceeding the maximum connection lifetime, a connection can be lost because of small interruptions in the network link.

Comment: 1 and 2 I do. Regarding number 3: None of my queries take longer than 1-2 seconds. Can they ever take significantly more time than they take when I run them (they are based on my server performance and not the client's, right)?Regarding number 4: it seems to always be happening as a result of the same method, which leads me to think it's not just some random interuption.

Answer (score 2):

Does the mysql server timeout the connections? It could also be a kernel thing, if the connection is idle for a long time the underlying tcp connection might get killed.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 lines take 60+ seconds, so connection pool decides your connection is abandoned and closes it. Later your code tries to use connection, but it's already called off by connection pool.

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
[process rs]
```

As you are sure it's not long executeQuery(), make debug printing with connection/thread/request id and time for [process rs] part. If you see something like 50+ seconds for this part, you should optimize [process rs] or read data and stash them in memory before processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing removeAbandonedTimeout value to something like 20 or 15. Your maxWait is 10 seconds, but if the connections are getting abandoned, then you are waiting for 60 seconds before returning them.

Please note, this is not a solution, but just a test to see if your connections are actually hanging.